# Review Audits - room for improvement

Tags: support, review, review-audits

First impressions from the review audit system: I am slightly amused but more annoyed.

- The first two audits I got were ones that I had voted to close myself - so it was a mild form of deja vu
- yesterday I got 5 audits - seems a little heavy for one day - and the "congratulations, this was just a test" message disrupts my concentration.

I noticed that I was looking for tell tale signs on the posts before really dealing with the text. So it *might* be a good idea to reduce the frequency a bit.

Apart from that I want to +1 the appeals that evaluation should not happen before the reviewer clicks on "I am done".

Comment: I'm speculating, but when one runs for mod, I would suspect the system SHOULD expose them to higher review audit prejudice.  Before I got bothered about the review audits, I would wait for the mod election to end and see if it just goes away.

Comment: Doesn't apply here :-))

Comment: Sorry.  I had you confused with @Mitch.  And upvote.

Comment: I was about to post the same question. I totally agree with everything you said: **deja vu** (we should not be tested with questions we interacted with), **frequency** (users that fail the test should be exposed to more tests, and the ones that pass should get less tests), **"I am done"** (I was tested by this http://askubuntu.com/q/416380/65926 and I rememberer something similar was asked before, so I pressed *close* just to search for a duplicate and BAM, I failed the test).

Comment: Failing prior to "I am done" seems extreme. Failing for attempting to leave a comment on a good answer seems ludicrous at best.

Comment: I agree that the frequency can be a bit extreme (to be kind) and in some cases borders on annoying. My response to the annoyance factor has been to just go away for awhile. I doubt this is the desired result so perhaps revisiting the audit frequency code would be helpful.

Comment: Is anything actually done about this? I just reviewed 21 questions and late answers and had 5 tests! waisting 15min of my time, because I made the effort of leaving a long custom comment on those, only to discover that they had already been deleted.

Answer (score 5):

With 6 audits under your belt in 3 days, you're near the top of the list for "most audited". Mostly, that's just because you do a lot of reviews, but some of it is due to plain old luck...

Review audit *frequency* is semi-random: you shouldn't get in a situation where *every* review is an audit, but if you're unlucky you can end up encountering them fairly often: so far, you're averaging about one audit per 20 reviews; expect this to vary over time.

Comment: <sarcastic> ah, I get the message, "there are far to many reviewers, you should review less than 20 posts per day" </sarcastic> - please understand that I am not complaining (and I had definitely more than 6 in the first two days) - it was intended as feedback, no immediate "solution" was expected.

Comment: Oops, I was just looking at one queue - you're up to 14 across all of them as of right now.

Answer (score 3):

The review audit system really isn't that smart, which is why you get questions that you have already dealt with.

Remember the audits aren't here to test *you*, they're here to catch robo reviewers who fly through the review queue applying the same action to every post. They *should* be easy for you to catch.

I do agree however, that the frequency could be lowered a bit, they are starting to get disruptive. I also disagree with how close vote review audits work, especially with duplicates as explained in this question on MSO: [Close vote review audit flawed - fails without casting vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179651/close-vote-review-audit-flawed-fails-without-casting-vote).

<sup>I started this as a comment, but it kinda evolved beyond that, so here it is</sup>

Comment: According to @shog9 ("Remember: review audits are meant to be helpful, a tool for teaching new reviewers what is expected and maybe staving off fatigue in experienced reviewers.") the purpose is not **only** to catch robo reviewers. If it were then just one audit/week would be sufficient. I don't really **want** to *catch* them (in the sense "I see the trap").

Comment: @guntbert Yes, they have that purpose too. You should want to catch the robo reviewers though, they hurt the site and make review useless. By "catch" I don't mean eternally ban, but, like Shog said, teach them what review is really all about. They should get eternally banned however if they refuse to review properly after many lessons. Review is an important aspect of site moderation, not a game.