# Tests are now one third of review tasks

Tags: discussion, review

Yesterday I reviewed about ten posts, of which three where tests. Today in just three reviews I got a test. I find this an overkill, especially since I passed all the tests so far. Not very motivating wasting time like this.

I would suggest tests to be conducted permanently, but on a lower volume, say three per week.

Comment: Well, I got one test in ~200 reviews. Maybe the algorithm is using some other data (say, reviewer discordance) to decided how many tests a reviewer needs?

Comment: What is "reviewer discordance"?

Comment: An awkward way to say that you have two differing reviewer decisions on the same post: say, one upvotes it while the other downvotes. Or one performs a heavy edit while the other indicates that no action is needed. But I'm only speculating here.

Comment: See  http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8552/44179 audits are random, so it should calm down. It did for me.

Comment: @Wilf Nope, mods still get review audits, I got one today actually ;)

Comment: @Seth Half of mine yesterday seemed to be tests - though the ones today were better :D

Comment: Hmm.  I've only gotten three tests over dozens of reviews.

Comment: @Seth Nice to see the ♦ next to your name.

Comment: I have never run into a test yet, is there a rep cap or number completed required to begin to get audited, or is it for certain review queue's only?